# How do I get the email address from linkedin with people/~:(id,.)?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

When I'm using the API call below I **don't** get the email address:

```
people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,summary,date-of-birth,email-address,positions,educations,skills:(skill,proficiency),languages:(language,proficiency),location,public-profile-url,phone-numbers,im-accounts,twitter-accounts,picture-urls::(original))
```

But when I using the API call below I **do** get the email address:

```
people/~/email-address
```

Has anyone have a clue?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be working for me, try to debug by starting with one field (email-address) and add other fields to see where is goed wrong, maybe you defined a field which is not in the current API.

Comment: I had to active the new API (refresh cache at linkedin side). After I changed the API call, it worked and when I changed it back again it worked also. Strange but I works now!

Answer (score 0):

How to get email-address field by specify Linkedin userID

Comment: Replace the `~` with `id=[THE_ID_OF_THE_USER]`, this will be something like: `people/id=abcdef/email-address`

Comment: Next time, try to add your question as a question and not like an answer. It will help you get the answer you looking for quicker!

Comment: i did not explain well, i mean email-address of user's connections, i go through linkedin policy, they does not expose the email fields.

Comment: It's an easy way to start spam, so obvious they don't support that.